# HTTPS and route www.domain.com -> domain.com on AWS elastic beanstalk (works with chrome, but not safari)

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk instance (without load balancer) running on AWS.

Via Route 53, I have an alias from my domain-name "example.com" and "www.example.com" to the Elastic Beanstalk instance.
Works just fine.

I also reroute every http request to https following the tutorial here:
https://blog.lucasferreira.org/howto/2017/07/21/set-up-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificate-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-single-instance.html

What's weird now is that if go in Chrome to "www.example.com" or "example.com" everything works just fine and it's forwarded to "https://example.com".
If I do the same in Safari and Firefox, I get an error message saying that "This connection is not private" for https://www.example.com" . 
The reason is that the certificate is for domain.com, but not for www.example.com

I'm a newbie in web services, really. What am I doing wrong here?

- Do I need to install two certificates, one for domain.com and one for www.example.com? How would I do that based on the tutuorial above?
- Can I re-route traffic from www.example.com to example.com in another way so I don't need another certificate?
- Or do I make a basic mistake w.r.t. the www.example.com anyway, and I shouldn't need both www and non-www?

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a second rewrite condition before the https rewrite. If the url begins with `www.` then rewrite the URL to `https://example.com`, removing the `www.`

This avoids redirecting your URL to https whilst including `www.` which isn't covered by your SSL.

Using the tutorial you have linked to above, your VirtualHost config would look like this:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
  </VirtualHost>
```